# How can I unit test responses from the webapp WSGI application in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine

I'd like to unit test responses from the Google App Engine webapp.WSGIApplication, for example request the url '/' and test that the responses status code is 200, using [GAEUnit](http://code.google.com/p/gaeunit). How can I do this?

I'd like to use the webapp framework and GAEUnit, which runs within the App Engine sandbox (unfortunately [WebTest](http://pythonpaste.org/webtest/) does not work within the sandbox).

Answer (score 13):

I have added a [sample application](http://code.google.com/p/gaeunit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/sample_app) to the GAEUnit project which demonstrates how to write and execute a web test using GAEUnit.  The sample includes a slightly modified version of the '[webtest](http://pythonpaste.org/webtest/index.html)' module ('import webbrowser' is commented out, as recommended by David Coffin).

Here's the 'web_tests.py' file from the sample application 'test' directory:

```
import unittest
from webtest import TestApp
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
import index

class IndexTest(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    self.application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', index.IndexHandler)], debug=True)

  def test_default_page(self):
    app = TestApp(self.application)
    response = app.get('/')
    self.assertEqual('200 OK', response.status)
    self.assertTrue('Hello, World!' in response)

  def test_page_with_param(self):
    app = TestApp(self.application)
    response = app.get('/?name=Bob')
    self.assertEqual('200 OK', response.status)
    self.assertTrue('Hello, Bob!' in response)
```

Comment: Patching `webtest/__init__.py` is no longer necessary, as webbrowser is only imported by the `webtest.app:showbrowser` function if it's called. See https://github.com/Pylons/webtest/commit/78076424c219935ee556aab84d943d5949530531 and https://github.com/Pylons/webtest/commit/53889b57fe16c57fd7f532953d2e15bfaba7e5b3

Answer (score 2):

Actually WebTest does work within the sandbox, as long as you comment out

```
import webbrowser
```

in webtest/__init__.py

Comment: Patching `webtest/__init__.py` is no longer necessary, as webbrowser is only imported by the `webtest.app:showbrowser` function if it's called. See https://github.com/Pylons/webtest/commit/78076424c219935ee556aab84d943d5949530531 and https://github.com/Pylons/webtest/commit/53889b57fe16c57fd7f532953d2e15bfaba7e5b3