# webtest for google app engine

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine

Can someone please provide a multipart/form-data POST example based on:

[How can I unit test responses from the webapp WSGI application in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107675/how-can-i-unit-test-responses-from-the-webapp-wsgi-application-in-google-app-eng)

```
import unittest
from webtest import TestApp
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
import index

class IndexTest(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    self.application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', index.IndexHandler)], debug=True)

  def test_default_page(self):
    app = TestApp(self.application)
    response = app.get('/')
    self.assertEqual('200 OK', response.status)
    self.assertTrue('Hello, World!' in response)

  def test_page_with_param(self):
    app = TestApp(self.application)
    response = app.get('/?name=Bob')
    self.assertEqual('200 OK', response.status)
    self.assertTrue('Hello, Bob!' in response)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def test_submit_form(self):
    app = TestApp(self.application)
    response = app.post('/', { 'name': 'John' })
    self.assertEqual('200 OK', response.status)
```

To test POST requests just use `app.post()` instead of `app.get()`. The second argument to `app.post` is your form data.

[See documentation for webtest](http://webtest.pythonpaste.org/en/latest/index.html#making-requests).